# navbar blocking textbox when refocusing and typing

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, textfield, scrolltop

On my website, and seeimingly on every page on the internet that I'm searching on this problem exists, and I am wondering if anyone has a solution to this.

If a website has a navbar at the top, then you click your cursor on a textbox, scroll down on the page so the textbox is out of view. Start typing and the page will scroll back to the tetbox that you are typing on, except the navbar will be blocking the actual text, there is no offset to account for that navbar height.

Here it is in action on w3schools.com for example:
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp

I have set my cursor to the "Last name:" field.
[image]

Now I scroll down so the field is out of view.

[image]

Now start typing again. You will see the website scroll back to the field so it can be in view at the top of the page. But note that the navbar at the top is blocking it.

[image]

This is prevalent all over the internet. w3schools for example and even facebook.
Has anyone every noticed and solved this issue? I don't even know where to start.

Comment: It happens on this website as well!

Comment: You could *technically* disable scroll if an element has focus using javascript. But as you can guess by literally every professional website on the internet, I wouldn't recommend it as it's not an issue for GUI.